# Expanding the size of 2d array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 2d matrix `arr` in MATLAB with of size `10x10`.If i need to increase it to say `20x20` do I need to create a new array of size 20x20 and copy all the contents of `arr` into it.Or is there some way to just expand the size of arr and make it into `20x20` without having to copy all the elements in a new array?

Comment: Just be careful, you should not expand the size of an array in a loop, since it takes time to do it, the best option is always to first init your array to the max size it will reach if it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>> arr = ones(10); % your input matrix
>> arr(20,20) = 0;
>> size(arr)

ans =
20    20
```

**Smaller sized example:**

```
>> arr = ones(3);
>> arr(5,5) = 0

arr =

     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Seems so obvious, yet didn't even think about it, nice one

Answer (score 0):

Matlab automatically increases the array size, if the preallocated space is too small. However this is inefficient, so you should create a new larger array and copy the contents.

```
smallArray = zeros(10,10, 'int32') %creates a 10x10 int array

largerArray = zeros(20,20,'int32') %creates larger array
largerArray(1:10,1:10) = smallArray; %copies the 10x10 array to the upper left of the large array
```

Comment: how is creating a new array and copying the values more efficient than resizing the old one?

Comment: The problem is, that if you have e.g. a 10 row matrix. Then say you want to add 10 more rows using a for loop. Then for each loop the matrix is resized, first to have 11 rows, then 12, etc.... So you better resize it to have 20 rows first and then add the new rows. Sorry, didn't express myself very clear.